# no notification after update

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-730, push-notifications

i just had an update yesterday for my windows phone (windows 10 mobile). Now my whatsapp and telegram apps receives new message if only i open the apps. It doesnt shows any notification at all. Only the push emails works. Can you help me with it? I already set it so that those apps can run in background. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with the same apps. Also, they are not exist in Notifications and action settings (no Whatsapp and Telegram app in the list of apps with notifications).

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to *Settings->System->Notifications & Actions*.
2. Make sure Notification for Whatsapp is turned on.
3. Also enable *Show notification in action center* for the app.
4. Adjust Banner notification, sound and vibration setting to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable messages and actions (settings > system) for WhatsApp and the WhatsApp privacy setting in (settings > privacy). Then shutdown your phone en start it up again. Enable the options again and your set! :)